# Getting 'Invalid argument' error when using IOCTL

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl, block-device

My userspace program is like this(this is only part of code):

```
char path[SIZE];
printf( "Enter the path of the block device to add or remove: ");
fgets(path, SIZE, stdin);
path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = '\0';

int fd = open( path, O_RDWR );

if( fd < 0 )
{
   perror( "Failed to open device" );
   exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

while( 1 )
{
    int input;

    printf( "Enter a number [ 0 for add and 1 for remove ]: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );

    switch( input )
    {
        case 0:
        if( ioctl( fd, MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD, &path ) < 0 )
        {
          perror( "Failed to add device" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        break;

        case 1:
        if( ioctl( fd, MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_REMOVE, &path ) < 0 )
        {
           perror( "Failed to remove device" );
           exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        break;

        case 2:
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    }
```

in '.h' file I have defined custom IOCTL commands -

```
#define MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD    _IOWR('M', 1, char*)
#define MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_REMOVE _IOWR('M', 2, char*)
```

in driver/module code -

```
static int device_ioctl( struct block_device *dev, fmode_t mode, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg )
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "in ioctl");
  int ret;
  char path[SIZE];
  switch( cmd )
  {
     case MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD:
     if( copy_from_user( path, (char *)arg, SIZE ) )
     {
         return -EFAULT;
     }
   
     path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = '\0';
     register_block_device(path);
     printk( KERN_INFO "Device added\n" );
     break;

     case MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_REMOVE:
     if( copy_from_user( path, (char *)arg, SIZE ) )
     {
         return -EFAULT;
     }

     unregister_block_device();
     printk( KERN_INFO "Device removed\n" );
     break;

     default:
     return -ENOTTY;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But every time when I call IOCTL from userspace, I am getting invalid argument error.
I verified changing magic numbers but didn't succeed.
Can you plz help me with this?

*EDIT* Note that these aren't full code snippets.

Comment: Are you *sure* about ` &path` as an argument? If `path` is a pointer, then `&path` will have the type `char **`. If `path` is an array, then `&path` will have the type `char (*)[SIZE_OF_ARRAY]`. Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Also, what does your `device_ioctl` function return if there's no error? Again, please try to create a [mre] to show us. And you should probably add a check to make sure that `open` doesn't fail.

Comment: Yeah, check now

Comment: How do we know that your `device_ioctl` doesn't return `-EINVAL` (which is the error you claim to get) later in the code if you don't show us the whole function? How do we know you even have a `return 0;` to signal no error at the end of the function? If the function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement, then using the returned value will lead to *undefined behavior*. And what happens if `open` fails? ***Always*** have error checking, especially for any code relating to user-input. For testing, hard-code the path, and make sure that `open` succeeds.

Comment: You're right. Check now added full code

Comment: `_IOWR('M', 1, char*)` This say that the argument should be a `char *`. With `&path` you pass an argument of type `char (*)[SIZE]`. This is really not the same. What happens if you pass plain `path` as the `ioctl` argument? That will decay to `&path[0]` which have the expected type `char  *`.

Comment: Same error when I passed plain path in ioctl(fd, MY.., path)

Comment: So, whether `in ioctl` is printed into dmesg when you run your program? If it is not printed, then the problem is not with the magic number, but with the path to device or with the way you register your `device_ioctl` function. You need to add terminating `\n` for make `printk` reliable.

Comment: *If* your `device_ioctl` function is called, then add more `printk` calls to be able to trace exactly everything, including values of all variables each time you change them.

Comment: Ok I'll do that

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes you are right. 'in ioctl' this msg hasn't been printed in dmesg output. I also printed path from the user space it's /dev/sdb as expected.

Comment: So you're trying to call your own IOCTL call on another device? But IOCTL calls are *device-specific*. You can't just create your own device and IOCTL calls, and then expect them to work on a totally different and unrelated device. What is your actual problem or assignment? What is your device supposed to do?

Comment: And if you try to do an IOCTL on a device that doesn't support that specific IOCTL then of course you will get an error.

Comment: We have created a block driver which traces operations performed on block device. I think its possible to use custom IOCTL calls for my own device.

Comment: "We have created a block driver which traces operations performed on block device." - So it could be that this tracing doesn't work as you expected. And we have no idea how you perform that tracing, since the code in the question post doesn't exhibit such behavior at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to do your own device-IOCTL calls on a totally different device.

If, as you claim in a comment, that you `open` the `/dev/sdb` device, then you can't do the IOCTL calls on it. You must open *your own* device, then call the IOCTL on that device:

```
// Error checking omitted
int mydevice = open("/dev/myowndevicefile", O_RDWR);

ioctl(mydevice, MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD, path);
```

Comment: No, our block driver is such that if you pass path as /dev/sdb it will start tracing its operations any read or write (its in working condition). So, I am developing a userspace app that will use ioctl commands to start and disable tracking that device (register and unregister functions).

Comment: @SumitPatil But you're not only passing `path` as an argument, you're using that `path` (to `/dev/sdb`) as the actual ***device*** to perform the IOCTL on. You must do it on ***your*** device. You're doing `MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD` **on** the `/dev/sdb` device, which doesn't have that IOCTL. What you're currently doing is basically (pseudo-code) `ioctl("/dev/sdb", MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD, "/dev/sdb")` when you should be doing it like `ioctl("/dev/yourdevice", MY_BLOCK_DEVICE_ADD, "/dev/sdb")` Do you see the difference? Do you *understand* the difference?